How philosophy explains a strong sense of purpose?

The great Greek philosopher Aristotle argued that everything has a
purpose or goal. For humans, the aim is reaching a state of ultimate
happiness or Eudaimonia. According to Aristotle, happiness is
achieving health, wealth, knowledge, and friends while keeping ethics
in mind.
https://lairdsuperfood.com/blogs/news/how-does-our-sense-of-purpose-affect-our-well-being

I disagree with the view that the ultimate purpose for an intellectually developed human bean is to get healthy, get high and pleased.
For me, the higher purpose is to perfect some form of activity and achieve something meaningful for other people around you.
Also, advancing toward your purpose usually means taking the pain and making significant sacrifices.

Working on a research article - andrós

@andrós - Aristotle lived 2.5 thousand years ago, but little has changed since then. If you ask a modern day American, what is the purpose of his life, you might hear: "To have some fun".

Maybe little has changed since because that's just the way it is. Keep in mind that not all people get happy by the same way, maybe the satisfaction of working hard to make significant research contribution is your own way to feel good about yourself and "have some fun".

@armand - But did you notice that we'd come full circle? You get your endorphins usually when you do something for your life's purpose (procreate, for example).

@andrós - if you mean OOP, then, object including state and purpose, maybe.

I agree with: "perfect some form of activity and achieve something meaningful for other people around you". It's a good start.

What constitutes our life's purpose is entirely your opinion. Particularly, that our purpose in life is to reproduce relies nor on facts nor reason. Therefore we are not coming full circle: you are just taking the problem backward by assuming out of nowhere that if we receive oxytocin for something it must be purposeful.
